# Why does the character ë have its own ISO code (EB) but ė doesn't?

Tags: encoding, fonts, character-encoding, iso

I'm running into a tricky issue with the character ė (small e with one dot above it). I'm specifically using FPDF to generate PDF files in PHP and it won't support the ė character.

I noticed on Wikipedia the ISO hex for ė is the same as ë. Both are EB.
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ė](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%96)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8B

Why are ė and ë considered the same character in ISO?

Answer (score 3):

You get things wrong.

ISO is a standard organization, and it has many standards. Unicode has also an parallel ISO standard (ISO 10646). And we had other ISO standards for texts.

You are looking instead the ISO 8859, which is made by various parts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859

This is a 8-bit character encoder, so you have a very limited character set (256 minus 32 characters). For this reason there are many different parts, and one choose what better fit on own country/language. You may choose Latin-1 for West European languages, or better Latin-9 (part 15) which includes the "new" character: Euro symbol (currency).

In your example, you have the language specific codes `EB`. In part 13 (Latin-7) it is `ė` (baltic), but in part 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, 14, 15, and part 16 it is `ë`. As you see, this is variant is used in many more languages, so it is available in most of the ISO 8859 parts. In the page I linked above, you see also the table with every variant per code/value.

The main problem now it is to detect the original encoding. This could be very problematic for people who cannot asses which the language, so the spelling, of a text.  For new text, better to use Unicode, which is unique (real text doesn't have Unicode byte pattern)